# Product of Norm of Vectors

Tags: normed-spaces

I have a simple question ...

Consider two vectors of same length $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$. This identity holds:

$|\mathbf{x}'\mathbf{y}|$ $\leq$ $\|\mathbf{x}\|$  $\|\mathbf{y}\|$

Then is should follow that: 
$\mathbf{x}'\mathbf{y}$ $\leq$ $\|\mathbf{x}\|$  $\|\mathbf{y}\|$

Right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct, assuming $x'y$ is real. Indeed, $a \leq |a|$ for any real number.